# How to work with Excel in c#?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, excel

I have a template/format in excel which has to be used to generate salary slips. I have saved it in a document library and using interop, open an instance of it in a workbook programmatically. After I populate it with elements I retrieve from a list, I have to save it as a file in another document library. How do I do it?

I am trying to implement it in an autohosted app.

Comment: Are you using sharepoint online or sharepoint foundation 2010?

Comment: I am using cloud version of sharepoint

Comment: I am able to open an excel file stored in a library, am able to modify it. I want to store the file in another library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i understand your question, After doing modification you can upload the file to sharepoint using CSOM.

```
 ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://spdevinwin");

 Web web = context.Web;

   FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
 newFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Work\Files\17580_FAST2010_S05_Administration.pptx");
  newFile.Url = "17580_FAST2010_S05_Administration 4MB file uploaded via client OM.pptx";

    List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
 Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);
  context.Load(uploadFile);
  context.ExecuteQuery();
```

so you can set newFile.Content with your files byte array.

Please correct me if i am not able to understand you.

Comment: I am using this for an autohosted app for the cloud version of sharepoint. I am not sure if this would work for cloud!

Comment: You can try this as this is client object model. But just remember to create credentials as SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
 
    foreach (char c in "yourpassword".ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
 
    clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("loginname@yoursite.onmicrosoft.com", passWord);

Comment: I know that, but whats the location of the edited file in sharepoint cloud. As I said, i've opened a file in a document library and edited it. What param should I give to ReadAllBytes? My source is a worksheet object. I dont have the location of this object!!

Comment: So what you can do is download the file first then upload that file to other location. Is there any problem with this approach?

Comment: Also you should use provider hosted apps as Microsoft discontinues Autohosted Apps model in SharePoint Online.http://thuansoldier.net/?p=4058

Comment: About the approach, downloading and re-uploading is not an option. Looks like I have to come with an all-together different approach.:/

Comment: Autohosted apps is what the client required so I cant comment on that.